# Sending a string from Windows store app to a WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps, app-config

I have got a Windows Store App, and within this Store app I have a textbox wich the user types in information wich then gets sent to my WCF service.

Now here is the problem. When the user types in 1-50 characters and then decides to send the information everything works just fine. But.. when the user types in more than 50 characters my App is unable to send the information.

I have tried to change/add maxArrayLength, maxStringContentLength, maxBufferPoolSize and maxBufferSize within the app.config file. To a higher value than it had before but with no success.

So my question is: Am I able to send more than 50 characters or is there a limit? And if it is possible so send more than 50 characters.. how can I do that?

----------------------EDIT--------------------

This is how I send my info to the WCF

```
            var server = new EmployeeAssisterClient();

            var timeReportList = _timeReport.GetAll();

            foreach (var timeReport in timeReportList)
            {
                if (!result)
                    break;

                result = server.RegisterTimeAsync(new EmployeeAssisterWCF.TimeReport
                    {
                        CustomerId = timeReport.CustomerId,
                        Date = timeReport.Date,
                        InvoiceText = timeReport.InvoiceText,
                        TimeInvoiced = (int) timeReport.InvoicedTime,
                        TimeWorked = (int) timeReport.WorkedTime,
                        UserId = timeReport.UserId,
                    }).Result;
            }
```

The RegisterTime method in the WCF

```
public Boolean RegisterTime(TimeReport timeReport)

    {            
        var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TimeReport values (@employeeId, @customerNumber, @invoicedTime, @workedTime, @date, @invoiceText, @Invoiced)", connection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@employeeId", timeReport.UserId));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customerNumber", timeReport.CustomerId));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@invoicedTime", timeReport.TimeInvoiced));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@workedTime", timeReport.TimeWorked));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", timeReport.Date));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@invoiceText", timeReport.InvoiceText));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Invoiced", false));

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And my bindings

```
<bindings>
  <netHttpBinding>
    <binding name="netHttpBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                 maxBufferSize="2097152" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2097152"> 
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Regards
Niklas

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx

Comment: Updated with some code.

Comment: What is the length of `invoiceText` in DB?

Comment: You were right there l4V. It was set to 50. Such a simple mistake. Thanks :)